# Images doesn't show in media print with Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, barcode

I have an application which prints barcodes using images for each column (**p.png**) and the same for spacing (b.png) as follow:

```
<img src="imagens/p.png" width="1" height="50" border="0">
<img src="imagens/b.png" width="1" height="50" border="0">
<img src="imagens/p.png" width="1" height="50" border="0">
<img src="imagens/b.png" width="2" height="50" border="0">
<img src="imagens/p.png" width="2" height="50" border="0">
[...]
```

I didn't use any of css to change img in `@media print`.

The problem is: Chrome doesn't print some imgs ( p.png ).

**1. Original barcode**

[image]

**2. Print in Chrome**

[image]

**3. Print in Firefox**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative Solution**: Use SVG to generate your barcodes!

I found a library to which creates 'ITF' barcodes without errors: https://github.com/kreativekorp/barcode

```
include 'barcode.php';

$generator = new barcode_generator();

/* Generate SVG markup. */
$symbology = 'itf';
$data = '23790198019000000053081017674607670300000001000';
$options['w'] = '50';
$options['p'] = '2';
$svg = $generator->render_svg($symbology, $data, $options);
echo $svg;
```

> Many thanks to @kreativekorp for this awesome php library.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative solution**: Use javascript canvas to solve this problem.

I create a code in codePen for use in all browsers:

https://codepen.io/eltonsrc/pen/OpXyrQ

**HTML**:

```
<div style="width: 600px">
  <canvas id="barcode" class="barcode">
    Code for browsers without canvas support. For example:
    <img src="blackBar.gif" width="1" height="50">
    <img src="whiteBar.gif" width="1" height="50">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.barcode {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var barCode = (function (){
  this.WHITE = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
  this.BLACK = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  this.THIN_BAR = 1;
  this.THICK_BAR = 3;

  this.lastPixel = 0;

  this.drawBar = function (barWidth, color) {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    this.ctx.fillRect(this.lastPixel, 0, barWidth, this.canvas.height);
    this.lastPixel += barWidth;
  };

  this.draw2of5BarCode = function (barcodeNumber) {
    var barCodes = ['00110', '10001', '01001', '11000', '00101', '10100', '01100', '00011', '10010', '01010'];

    for (var f1 = 9; f1 >= 0; f1--) {
      for (var f2 = 9; f2 >= 0; f2--) {
        var f = f1 * 10 + f2;
        var texto = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          texto += barCodes[f1].substr(i, 1) + barCodes[f2].substr(i, 1);
        }
        barCodes[f] = texto;
      }
    }

    // begin of barcode
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.BLACK);
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.WHITE);
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.BLACK);
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.WHITE);

    if (barcodeNumber.length % 2 != 0) {
      barcodeNumber = '0' + barcodeNumber;
    }

    do {
      var i = Number(barcodeNumber.substr(0, 2));
      if (barcodeNumber.length == 2) {
        barcodeNumber = '';
      } else {
        barcodeNumber = barcodeNumber.substr(2, barcodeNumber.length - 2);
      }

      var f = barCodes[i];

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
        if (f.substr(i, 1) == '0') {
          this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.BLACK);
        } else {
          this.drawBar(this.THICK_BAR, this.BLACK);
        }

        if (f.substr(i + 1, 1) == '0') {
          this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.WHITE);
        } else {
          this.drawBar(this.THICK_BAR, this.WHITE);
        }
      }
    } while(barcodeNumber.length > 0);

    this.drawBar(this.THICK_BAR, this.BLACK);
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.WHITE);
    this.drawBar(this.THIN_BAR, this.BLACK);
  }

  this.drawBarcode = function (canvasId, barcodeNumber) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);

    // verify canvas support
    if (!this.canvas.getContext) {
      return;
    }

    this.lastPixel = 0;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.draw2of5BarCode(barcodeNumber);
  };

  return this;
})();

barCode.drawBarcode('barcode', '856000000005227702201707619934651263800000000003');
```